# Apparent paradox in the use of certain integration formulas

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

---

### background

here is a formula which we all know in integral:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx
$$
and this, too:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{\frac{b+a}{2}}f(x)+f(a+b-x)dx
$$
and we also know, in  graphic view, these formulas could work because the $f(x)\space$ and the  $f(a+b-x)\space$ are symmetric to each other in $[a,b]$ and the axis of their symmetry is $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

so that we could  'fold them up'  to a smaller range and calculate it both.

---

### question body statement

now, what if we 'fold up' the range again?

$$let \space b_{1}=\frac{a+b}{2},\space f_{1}(x)=f(x)+f(a+b-x)$$
and we get these below:
$$\int_{a}^{b_{1}}f_{1}(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b_{1}}f_{1}(2b_{1}-x)dx
$$
$$
\int_{a}^{b_{1}}f_{1}(x)dx=\int_{a}^{\frac{b_{1}+a}{2}}f_{1}(x)+f_{1}(2b_{1}-x)dx
$$
they also could work, and $\int_{a}^{b_{1}}f_{1}(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$,right?

suppose above equations could make sense,
then we keep on doing this procedure, what will happen?

first,we define some variables
$$b_{n}=\frac{a+b_{n-1}}{2},b_{0}=b,
$$
$$
f_{n}(x)=f_{n-1}(x)+f_{n-1}(2b_{n-1}-x),
$$
$$
I_{n}=\int_{a}^{b_{n}}f_{n}(x)dx
$$

as a result, we get a series:
$$\{I_{n}\}$$
as noted before, we also have a eternal equation:
$$\{I_{n}\}\equiv\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

---

### here comes the paradox!

if we let $n$ trend to $\infty$,we would get:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_{n}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$$
obviously ,right?

but, we also get:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=a
$$
that means:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_{n}=\int_{a}^{b_{n}}f_{n}(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a}f_{n}(x)dx=0
$$

why? how could this happen?

in graphic view, it is obvious, after infinite folding , the  area of the zone between the $f(x)$ and y=0 will trend to zero,
but in algebra view, this shall not happen.

how to explain the paradox?

Comment: Both the upper limit $b_n$ and the function $f_n$ depend on $n$, but you are only taking limit to $b_n$. In reality, the decrease in domain of integration is compensated by the increase in the number of terms in $f_n$, so you cannot separate those behaviors separately. In a very loose sense, $I_n$ looks like an indeterminate $\int_{a}^{a} \infty \, dx \approx 0 \cdot \infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee thank you,  but how to calculate indeterminate like this? Does it have any meaning  in graphic view?

Comment: I am not telling that an expression $\int_{a}^{a} \infty \, dx$ is well-defined. Rather, what I meant was that $|[a,b_n]|\to 0$ while the integrand $f_n$ kind of diverges, so you have to deal with a quantity of the form $$[\text{small length of interval}]\times[\text{large integrand}]$$

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to contain the keywords integral and formulas. It is important for retrieving a question.

Comment: For $I=\int_0^11 dx$, we get $I_1=\int_0^{1/2}2dx$, and $I_2 = \int_0^{1/4}4dx$, and $I_3 = \int_0^{1/8}8dx$, etc. Obviously $\lim I_n \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the graphical view it is *not* obvious that "after infinite folding" the area under the curve is zero.

Let's take a very simple example: a constant function, $f(x) = 1.$
Then 
$$f_1(x) = f(x) + f(a+b−x) = 1 + 1 = 2.$$
So in going from $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ to $\int_a^{b_1} f_1(x)\,dx$
we have cut the horizontal distance in half
($b_1 - a = \frac12(b - a)$)
but we have doubled the height of the graph.
Hence the area remains the same.
Fold again and you will have $\frac14$ as much horizontal distance,
but $4$ times as much height.

For non-constant functions you will usually find that $f_1 \neq 2f,$
that is, the function is not exactly doubled everywhere, 
but the *average* height of $f_1$ over $[a,b_1]$ will be twice the *average* height of $f$ over $[a,b].$
After $n$ folds you have a function $f_n$ whose average height over
$[a,b_n]$ is $2^n$ times the average height of $f$ over $[a,b].$
In other words, no area is ever lost under the graph, it just gets piled up higher and closer to the $y$-axis with every fold.

In order to sketch a graph of the integral *at* the limit, $b_\infty=a,$
you would have to somehow plot a function $f_\infty$ whose value on $[a,a]$ is exactly $2^\infty$ times the average value of $f$ over $[a,b].$
There is no such function in real analysis, but if you assume (incorrectly) that there is such a function that you can integrate on $[a,a],$
you will conclude that the integral is zero.

So one  mistake is assuming that there is any meaning at all to the integral
$\int_a^{b_\infty} f_\infty(x)\,dx,$ either arithmetically or graphically.
There is no graphical interpretation of what the integral would look like
"after infinite folding."

But there is actually another mistake: you assume that
you can evaluate a limit by jumping to the limiting case.
Consider this false "proof":
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac12 + \frac12 \\
  &= \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14 \\
  &= \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18
       + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 \\
  & \qquad\vdots \\
  &= \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n}
        \quad \text{($2^n$ terms)} \\
  & \qquad\vdots \\
  &= 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots \\
  &= 0.
\end{align}
The fallacy here is in the jump from a finite sum of non-zero terms
to the sum $0+0+0+\cdots$.
There's simply no justification for that step.